# Complex exponential map restricted to the rational numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, irrational-numbers

> Consider the mapping $$\varphi: \mathbb{Q} \to
> \mathbb{C}\\ \quad \qquad x \mapsto e^{2\pi i x}$$ What is the image
>   $\varphi(\mathbb{Q})$?

Intuitively I would say that it is a countable subset of $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Comment: Note that $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism. So it's a subgroup. What can you say about the elements of the subgroup? What is the kernel of $\varphi$?

Comment: The kernel of $\varphi$ is $\mathbb{Z}$. And my last thought was $$\varphi(\mathbb{Q}) = \bigcup_{n > 0}\bigcup_{0 \leq k < n} e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Firstly it's manifestly countable since $|f(X)|\le |X|$, you cannot increase cardinality using a function. As for density, just note that any element of $S^1$ is of the form $e^{i\theta}$ for some $0\le \theta <2\pi$, and so if you take a sequence of rational numbers $q_n\to\theta$ then by continuity of the exponential map you know that $e^{iq_n}\to e^{i\theta}$ proving density. In fact, you can say even a little more, namely that the image is the set of all *roots of unity*, i.e. elements of $S^1$ satisfying $x^n=1$ for some $n$, since $e^{ip/q}$ raised to the $q$ is $1$.