# Prove uniqueness of subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups

> Prove that for every $n > 0$ there exists a unique subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},+)$ of order $n$.

**Solution.** Based on my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000835/complex-exponential-map-restricted-to-the-rational-numbers/2000839#2000839), I will proceed by using the group homomorphism $$\varphi: \begin{cases}(\mathbb{Q},+) \to
(\mathbb{C},\cdot)\\ x \mapsto e^{2\pi i x}\end{cases}$$

Then $$\varphi(\mathbb{Q}) = \bigcup_{n > 0} \bigcup_{0 \leq k < n} e^{(2\pi i k)/n} := \mathcal{R} := \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, z^n = 1\}$$ and $$\ker(\varphi) = \mathbb{Z}$$ Hence by the first isomorphism theorem $$\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \cong\mathcal{R}$$ Now the existence follows from $$\left\langle e^{(2\pi i)/n}\right\rangle = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : z^n = 1\}$$ since $e^z = 1$ if and only if $z/(2\pi i) \in \mathbb{Z}$ but this only happens if $k = 0$ for $0 \leq k < n$.

Uniqueness. Assume we have $H \leq \mathcal{R}$ with $|H| = n$. Then $h^n = 1$ for any $h \in H$ and so $H \subseteq \left\langle e^{(2\pi i)/n}\right\rangle$. But $|H| = n$ so $H = \left\langle e^{(2\pi i)/n}\right\rangle$ and we are done.

Is this correct?

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with complex analysis. Or complex numbers at all, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$  be an element of $\mathbb Q/  \mathbb Z$ of order dividing $n$. Then $x=(k/m) \mathbb Z$. Order of $x$ is $m$ then set $n=ml$. Then $x=(kl/n) \mathbb Z$.

Thus, $x\in <(1/n)\mathbb Z>$ which shows that $<(1/n)\mathbb Z>$ is uniqe subgroup of $\mathbb Q/  \mathbb Z$ of order $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider each element of Q/Z as its representative in [0,1). Wrap this interval and identify endpoints to make a circle. A group of order n has n elements. One element is 0. But they are also equally spaced because the least positive element can be added to any element to find an adjacent element. This fully determines the group as (1/n)Z+Z .

Comment: What's wrong with my solution?